# Trouble getting regex matching in gitlab CI to work

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have some trouble wrapping my head around the regex comparison in Gitlab-CI.

On the one hand, I have `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[[sS][kK][iI][pP]-?[cC][iI]\]/`which matches commit message `TICKET-01 [skip-ci] this should not be built` as expected, so I know the regex engine does *sometimes* match substrings without explicitly enclosing the patterns in catchall matchers.

On the other hand, I have `$CI_BRANCH_NAME =~ /[sS][kK][iI][pP]-?[cC][iI]/`( note: no brackets) which do NOT match `skip-ci-this-branch-will-never-build`, so in this instance, it does *not* match a substring.

In my mind, they should either both match, or both fail to match, but they don't.

I have tried to find more in-depth information on Gitlab CI regex matching, but came up blank.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: possibly the `-` symbol is infact different; there exist many different unicode characters that do look similar. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Character_codes

Comment: Good point on robustness, and for any other character than the simple minus character I would agree. That one however is so deeply rooted in IT (it's literally 7-bit ascii) that it is the same on virtually any machine in existence, bar some VERY exotic ones.

I can definitely say they are not different in my test, because I literally typed them on the same keyboard/machine combo I created the test branch on. Also I don't think it will *become* a problem because everyone in the team is working on provided hardware with the same managed settings.